# css javascript drop down menu list

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu

does anyone know how to do a drop down menu like gmail "more" link or facebook "Account" link??

Answer (score 1):

Look over here: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/resources/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/

This site has lots of solutions using plain Javascript or libraries like jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

A simple, but effective, [Google search](http://www.google.no/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=css+menu) would have yielded tons of results, but here's one to get you started :)

[Css menu maker](http://www.cssmenumaker.com/).

Comment: No worries, sometimes it takes a few different keywords to find a good one :)